# Angular ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on http request

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-http

Hi I am new to Angular and trying to create an app that uses the Spotify API. When I use my search component to search however nothing happens and I receive an error in console

> GET https://api.spotfiy.com/v1/search?query=adf&offset=0&limit=20&type=artist&market=US net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Here is the where the service is contained service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class SpotifyService{

private searchUrl:string;

constructor(private _http:Http){

 }

searchMusic(str:string, type="artist"){

this.searchUrl = `https://api.spotfiy.com/v1/search?query=${str}&offset=0&limit=20&type=${type}&market=US`;
return this._http.get(this.searchUrl).map(res => res.json());

}

}
```

search component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {SpotifyService} from '../../services/spotify.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'search',
  templateUrl: 'search.component.html',
  //providers:[SpotifyService]
})
export class SearchComponent{
  searchStr:string;

  constructor(private _spotifyService:SpotifyService){

  }

  searchMusic(){

    this._spotifyService.searchMusic(this.searchStr).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res.artist.items);

      })
  }

}
```

app.module

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { AboutComponent }  from './components/about/about.component';
import { SearchComponent }  from './components/search/search.component';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule  } from '@angular/http';
import { SpotifyService } from './services/spotify.service';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: SearchComponent },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
]

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, AboutComponent, NavbarComponent, SearchComponent ],
  providers:    [ SpotifyService ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the URL. You accidentally typed **spotfiy** instead of **spotify**. It happens :)